# Issue displaying SCSS styles with vue.js

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I'm creating a vue.js web app, and I'd like to use SCSS to help with the styling. I've installed `npm i node-sass sass-loader` and I've created a `vue.config.js` at root level. In it I have this set

```
module.exports = {
 css: {
  loaderOptions: {
   scss: {
       additionalData: `@import "@/styles/global.scss";`
   }
  }
 }
};
```

---

This is SCSS the folder structure

[image]

In every subfolder to the main `styles` folder I have a `_all.scss` that then imports every containing `.scss` file for that given subfolder. And in the `global.scss` all the subfolders `_all.scss` files gets imported.

```
// styles/base/_all.scss
@import 'reset.scss';
@import 'variables.scss';

// global.scss
@import 'base/all';
@import 'components/all';
```

---

My issue is that my web app doesn't load any of the `.scss` files or styles imported via the main `global.scss` file. I get no build errors, and if I for example remove the `_variables.scss` file, then I get an error that other `.scss` files can't access the declared scss variables. So that means that my `.scss` import method is woriking, but the styles aren't shown somehow.

Do I have to use every vue components `<style>` tag to do all the styling, or can I go about doing it the way I've structured it now?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not messing with the webpack config.

you can import your style in the main.js also

```
import '@/styles/global.scss';
```